# Удаление писем почты и delphi

Tags: indy, delphi, delphi-7

Всем привет! Удаляю сообщения из почты следующим образом:

```
IdPOP31.Host:='сервер';
  IdPOP31.Port:=110;   
  IdPOP31.Username:='имя';  
  IdPOP31.Password:='пароль';                    
  IdMessage1.Clear;                                          
  IdPOP31.Connect;                                          
  IdMessage1.CharSet:='utf-8';
  IdMessage1.Clear;                                         
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  lb_letters.Clear;
  j:=IdPOP31.CheckMessages;
  if IdPOP31.CheckMessages>0
  then for i:=1 to IdPOP31.CheckMessages do
  begin
    IdPOP31.RetrieveHeader(i, IdMessage1);
    if AnsiCompareText(IdMessage1.From.Address,'webmaster@mark-itt.ru')=0
    then begin
      IdPOP31.Retrieve(i, IdMessage1);
      IdPOP31.Delete(i);
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      p_attachment.Caption:=IntToStr(i)+'/'+IntToStr(j);
    end;
  end;
  IdPOP31.Disconnect;
```

В почтовом ящике огромное количество писем от одного получателя, хочу удалить все его письма. В принципе  всё работает, однако если я прерву работу "Ctrl+F2", то все письма остаются на месте. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы те письма, которые уже прошли проверку на совпадения адреса удалялись в случае прерывания работы приложения???

Comment: @АлександрЪ Отформатируйте код. Для этого есть кнопка "{}". Выделите код в своём сообщении и нажмите эту кнопку.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci как бы глупо это не звучало: теперь я знаю как его форматировать)

Comment: А если не прерывать работу приложения письма удаляются? Проверьте на каком-нибудь другом отправителе, где не так много писем.

Почему Вы не писали вот так:

      j := IdPOP31.CheckMessages;
        if j > 0 then
          for i := 1 to j do

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Да, если работу не прерывать, то письма удаляются, и да - проверял на отправителях, у которых мало писем)
По поводу кода - даже не заметил как-то и глупо написал, Вы правы)

Comment: Ну в таком случае, видимо, нужно делать `IdPOP31.Disconnect;` перед прерыванием работы программы. Закрывайте ее не по Ctrl+F2, а как обычно. А в событие формы `OnClose` добавьте `IdPOP31.Disconnect;`.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Кстати, если цикл не завершился, то я не могу закрыть проект нажатием на красный крестик в правом верхнем углу(( но по завершению цикла форма сразу закрывается.

Comment: Вынесите `Application.ProcessMessages;` из условия в основное тело цикла. А лучше сделайте для обработки писем отдельный поток.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci вынес Application.ProcessMessages; из условия в основное тело цикла: ситуация ничуть не изменилась, только в p_attachment.Caption теперь ничего не отображается. По поводу отдельных потоков: ранее не имел с ними дело, можете скинуть ссылку на хорошую литературу и/или пример?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая ссылка из гугла: http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=1370

[Все остальные ссылки](http://bit.ly/1nEXPhi)

Comment: Благодарю)